# SeekBar on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the seekbar in the navigation drawer. What's my mistake? In the application without the navigation drawer there is no problem. Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    TextView textView;
    SeekBar seekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            textView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Did you create it in your activity_main.xml ?

Comment: the seekBar is null add your layout xml

Comment: I create seekbar.xml and add in activity_main_drawer.xml  -   app:actionLayout="@layout/seekbar"

Comment: In this way, I was able to add a spinner :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your Seek bar is in Header View of Navigation Drawer in That Case You may :

```
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        profile_name = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        profile_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        profile_image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        setNavigationHeader();
```

You need to get the view of Header first and then find your Seek bar in it

If your view is not in header then this won't work.

You need to create your own Custom Navigation Drawer